# custom fonts, eot, not working

Tags: html, fonts, css, embedded-fonts

I cant get my custom fonts to work in IE7 and IE8:

http://i-creative.dk/iJob/

It works fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome...

For Firefox and Chrome the fonts are in TTF
And for IE, it's in EOT

However, it only works in IE9 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this css formatting instead:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontName';
    src: url('/path/to/font.eot?') format('eot'), 
         url('/path/to/font.otf') format('otf'), 
         url('/path/to/font.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

This is what I use (sans the otf, woff & svg instead). and I have never had any of the IE's not render the font.

Comment: I needed the IE9 section from  @adedoy 's answer in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Graublauweb; /*any name for your font*/
    src: url('Graublauweb.eot'); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
    src: url('Graublauweb.eot?') format('eot'),  /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('Graublauweb.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('Graublauweb.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('Graublauweb.svg#svgGraublauweb') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the correct mime type for EOT files. In apache, adding this to your .htaccess file should work.

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot
AddType font/ttf                      ttf
AddType font/otf                      otf
AddType font/x-woff                   woff
```