# Font Face not working on Windows but is on Mac & iPhone

Tags: css, windows, macos, fonts, font-face

I've got a staging website setup, and the paths are definitely working correctly. The fonts are working on browsers on my MacBook/my spare MacBook, and on my iPhone. But when my client checks the font on her Windows laptop, and I check it in Browser Stack on Windows the font doesn't work. Any ideas why this might be?

This is the code I'm using...

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'LemonTuesday';
src: url('fonts/LemonTuesday.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/LemonTuesday.otf') format('opentype'),
     url('fonts/LemonTuesday.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/LemonTuesday.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/LemonTuesday.svg#LemonTuesday') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

[Screenshot of it on Macbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY8Qd.png)
/ [Screeenshot of it on Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5c5x.png)

The fonts folder is within the same folder as my final main.css file.

I can't work out why this might be happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your client using older browsers? Is the website running with https? If it i https, you may refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748140/font-face-eot-not-loading-over-https) for some reference. And maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964161/custom-fonts-eot-not-working). You may also consider to create a test css with only eot to make sure eot file is working properly. Good luck.

Comment: also on a 2020 note: please remove those eot, otf, ttf, and svg rules. It's no longer 2012, none of those are even remotely relevant, let alone supported. server WOFF and WOFF2 and then debug _that_ situation. `eot` hasn't been supported for years, same for `svg`, and `otf`/`ttf` are full system fonts, not webfonts.

Comment: Thanks! Not used @font-face in years so sometimes hard to remember.